# Train Cascade Object Detector example in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to use the example from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/traincascadeobjectdetector.html) to detect a stop sign.

But when I change the image to search for stop signs in there are a huge number of false positives.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi i'm also trying the trainCascadeObjectDetector for detecting people but it doesn't show me a good results someone could help me plz . my data set contains 270 negative images and 450 postive images . other question please i need to know haw to test haar feature in trainCascadeObjectDetector('personDetector.xml',data ,negativeFolder,'FalseAlarmRate', 0.2, 'NumCascadeStages',18); i know that hog is the default feature . thank you :)

Comment: Please do not use answer slots to ask similar questions. You can use the comments block under the question, or start a new thread if your case is different enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong.  This particular example is there for a quick illustration, and it does not produce a very good detector. It trains a 5-stage detector from a very small training set.  A decent detector may have 20 stages or more, and you would need thousands of positive samples and negative images to train it.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) for more information.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know that.  I have noticed that it actually works pretty good on images that contain stop signs about the same size (in pixels) as the test image.  Do you happen to know of a more in depth explanation of how to train a cascade object detector in MATLAB than the one you provided?

Comment: Adding to what I previously wrote: So I guess you would say that the example is not very robust to changes in scale.  I have read that the algorithm used is pretty robust to changes in scale though.  Should I have to train the classifier with many different scales of the same images?

Comment: In this example the ObjectTrainingSize is set automatically to [33,32]. So stop signs smaller than that will not be detected, but the ones bigger than that should be. If they are not, then try decreasing ScaleFactor parameter of vision.CascadeObjectDetector.

Comment: I don't know of a better tutorial off hand. Is there anything specific that is not clear to you? Please keep in mind, that this is a toy example. You need vastly more data to get a useful object detector.  Also keep in mind that stop signs at oblique angles are not likely to be detected, because they would have a different aspect ratio.

Comment: So the particular object I am trying to train the detector for has a pretty constant aspect ratio.  But for my application the object is very wide compared to tall.  So when I turn the object 90 degrees the object has the opposite aspect ratio.  So do I need to train the detector with examples turned 90 degrees, or does the algorithm automatically train for orientation shifts in the plane like that?

Comment: This algorithm does not handle rotation very well. For example the face detector in `vision.CascadeObjecDetector` works up to about 15 degrees of in-plane rotation. So if your object can rotate in the image, you would need to train multiple detectors, one for each orientation.

Comment: @user8919, I am also facing the similar type of problem, I will suggest you read more about the trainCascadeObjectDetector by executing the command help trainCascadeObjectDetector.